# Overriding Default Primitive Type Handling in Json.Net

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, primitive

Is there a way to override the default deserialization behaviour of Json.net when handling primitive types? For example when deserializing the json array `[3.14,10,"test"]` to a type of `object[]` *3.14* will be of type `double` and *10* will be of type `long`. Is there anyway I can intercept or override this type decision so I could deserialize the values as `decimal` and `int` respectively?

I basically always want json integers to always return as `int` and floats to return as `decimal`. This will save me some having to inject `double` to `decimal` conversions in my code.

I've looked into extending `Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver` and implementing my own `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter` but I have not discovered any way to implement this desired override.

Example code to reproduce

```
object[] variousTypes = new object[] {3.14m, 10, "test"};
string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(variousTypes);
object[] asObjectArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object[]>(jsonString); // Contains object {double}, object {long}, object {string}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, this should work

```
public class MyReader : JsonTextReader
{
    public MyReader(string s) : base(new StringReader(s))
    {
    }

    protected override void SetToken(JsonToken newToken, object value)
    {
        object retObj = value;
        if (retObj is long) retObj = Convert.ChangeType(retObj, typeof(int));
        if (retObj is double) retObj = Convert.ChangeType(retObj, typeof(decimal));

        base.SetToken(newToken, retObj);
    }
}


object[] variousTypes = new object[] { 3.14m, 10, "test" };
string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(variousTypes);

JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
var asObjectArray = serializer.Deserialize<object[]>(new MyReader(jsonString));
```

Comment: JsonTextReader.SetToken isn't marked as virtual in my release of json.net 4.5.1, so the override is throwing a 'no suitable method for override'. Am I missing something?

Comment: @MatthewRuston My current Json.Net version is `4.0.5`.

Comment: looks like they removed the virtual property in a recent release. Strange.

Comment: @MatthewRuston It also works with `4.5.0.0`. I can say that It works with latest release.

Comment: Are you saying it worked for you on the latest release? Since the latest is Json.NET 4.5 Release 1 (4.5.1) on http://json.codeplex.com and the method is no longer marked as virtual.I managed to get it to work on 4.0.5 however.

Comment: @MatthewRuston , you are right. I got the same error with v4.5. I must have missed something.

Comment: This solution still ends up converting to a double, then a decimal. It has the potential to lose precision that you could otherwise get with parsing directly as a decimal. That said, looking at the Json.NET code I don't see any other solution besides changing Json.NET's implementation.

Comment: Why would JSON.NET even attempt to encode an Int64 as a JSON integer, whose range is limited to a double type, and then provide no override.  That's just blind truncation.  JSON.NET has serious issues.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the method [`JsonReader.SetToken(JsonToken, Object, Boolean)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader_SetToken_2.htm) is no longer virtual.  In more recent versions of Json.NET ([10.0.1](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/10.0.1) or later), one must override [`JsonReader.Read()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader_Read.htm) and do the necessary conversion there, then update the reader's value with the desired value type.

For instance, if you would prefer your `JsonTextReader` to return `Int32` instead of `Int64` whenever possible, the following reader and extension method will do the job:

```
public class PreferInt32JsonTextReader : JsonTextReader
{
    public PreferInt32JsonTextReader(TextReader reader) : base(reader) { }

    public override bool Read()
    {
        var ret = base.Read();

        // Read() is called for both an untyped read, and when reading a value typed as Int64
        // Thus if the value is larger than the maximum value of Int32 we can't just throw an 
        // exception, we have to do nothing.
        // 
        // Regardless of whether an Int32 or Int64 is returned, the serializer will always call
        // Convert.ChangeType() to convert to the final, desired primitive type (say, Uint16 or whatever).
        if (TokenType == JsonToken.Integer
            && ValueType == typeof(long)
            && Value is long)
        {
            var value = (long)Value;

            if (value <= int.MaxValue && value >= int.MinValue)
            {
                var newValue = checked((int)value); // checked just in case
                SetToken(TokenType, newValue, false);
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }
}

public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static T PreferInt32DeserializeObject<T>(string jsonString, JsonSerializerSettings settings = null)
    {
        using (var sw = new StringReader(jsonString))
        using (var jsonReader = new PreferInt32JsonTextReader(sw))
        {
            return JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings).Deserialize<T>(jsonReader);
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it as follows:

```
object[] variousTypes = new object[] { 3.14m, 10, "test" };
string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(variousTypes);
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    FloatParseHandling = FloatParseHandling.Decimal,
};
object[] asObjectArray = JsonExtensions.Int32PreferredDeserializeObject<object[]>(jsonString, settings);
// No assert
Assert.IsTrue(variousTypes.Select(o => o == null ? null : o.GetType()).SequenceEqual(asObjectArray.Select(o => o == null ? null : o.GetType())));
```

Notes:

- Both [`JsonSerializer`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_FloatParseHandling.htm) and [`JsonReader`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader_FloatParseHandling.htm) have a setting [`FloatParseHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_FloatParseHandling.htm) that controls whether floating point numbers from JSON are to be initially parsed as `double` or `decimal`.  Thus there is no reason to implement this conversion manually in `Read()`.
- By using `PreferInt32JsonTextReader` you can control how the serializer deserializes values of type `object`.  Previously integer JSON values would be unconditionally deserialized to `long` (or `BigInteger` if required).  Now `int` will be returned if possible.  This will also modify how column types are inferred by [`DataTableConverter`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/DataTableConverter.cs).
- Nevertheless, using `PreferInt32JsonTextReader` will not affect what happens when loading JSON into a `JToken` hierarchy with, say, [`JToken.Load()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Load.htm), because the method that builds the hierarchy, [`JsonWriter.WriteToken()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonWriter.cs#L559), automatically converts all integer values to `long`.

Sample source with preliminary unit tests [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/onJhxt).