# Newtonsoft JSON- Conversion to/from DataSet causes Decimal to become Double?

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I'm using Newtonsoft JSON to serialize a DataSet to binary JSON using the code below. When de-serializing back to a DataSet, the field type changes from a Decimal to a Double? Does anybody know what's going wrong?

Sample code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var ds = new DataSet();
  var dt = ds.Tables.Add();
  dt.Columns.Add("Test", typeof(Decimal));
  dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1.23345M });

  var data = DataSetToBinJSON(ds);

  var ds2 = BinJSONToDataSet(data);
  Console.WriteLine((ds2.Tables[0].Columns[0].DataType == typeof(Decimal)) ? "Passed" : string.Format("Failed- {0}", ds2.Tables[0].Columns[0].DataType));
  Console.ReadLine();
}



/// <summary>
/// Utility function to create an optimized Binary JSON version of a DataSet
/// </summary>
public static byte[] DataSetToBinJSON(DataSet dataSet)
{
  if (dataSet == null || dataSet.Tables == null || dataSet.Tables.Count == 0)
  {
    return null;
  }

  using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    using (var writer = new BsonWriter(ms))
    {
      var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
      serializer.Serialize(writer, dataSet);
      return ms.ToArray();
    }
  }
}


/// <summary>
/// Utility function to deserialize an optimized Binary JSON serialized DataSet
/// </summary>   
public static DataSet BinJSONToDataSet(byte[] dataBytes)
{
  if (dataBytes.Length == 0)
  {
    return null;
  }

  using (var ms = new MemoryStream(dataBytes))
  {
    using (var reader = new BsonReader(ms))
    {
      var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
      return serializer.Deserialize<DataSet>(reader);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not a bug, it's normal behavior. Json format does not distinguish between float/double/decimal types, but you can implement own JsonTextReader.

Solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/9916087/835720

Comment: @oakio- many thanks. Figured this out by simply checking the source! Was expecting Newtonsoft serialization to behave like: http://chrish.com.au/blog/json-netdeserializing-a-datatable/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy way to fix this set `FloatParseHandling = FloatParseHandling.Decimal`

**Example**:

```
    public class Foo
    {
        public object Value { get; set; }
    }

    Foo original = new Foo
        {
            Value = 1.23m
        };

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(original);

    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            FloatParseHandling = FloatParseHandling.Decimal //hint
        };
    Foo actual = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json, settings);

    // actual.Value.GetType() == 'Decimal'
```

Comment: Oakio. Your comment on the question was the answer, so I'm accepting the answer on this response. This is interesting, but not what I'm looking for. I was looking for 100% lossless DataSet Binary Json serialization, but it turned out I can do with the simple serialization.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it has something to do with the standard (XML) serialization of `DataSet` and `DataTable`.

If you write `DataSet` from the example to a file you'll see that information about the `DataTable` schema isn't provided. This can be determined when reading the XML file back into a table.

The data from your example written to a file gives this result:

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Table1>
    <Test>1.23345</Test>
  </Table1>
</NewDataSet>
```

When the `DataSet` with the `DataTable` has been read you can't change the type of the column (in my test case when going to/from XML the type is `string`) but you can `.Clone()` the `DataTable` and move/convert the data:

```
var clonedTable = ds.Tables[0].Clone();
clonedTable.Columns[0].DataType = typeof(decimal);
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Tables[0].Rows) {
    clonedTable.ImportRow(row);
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks, but this is Binary JSON, not XML? The conversion done by Newtonsoft uses its own DataSet JSON format, not the Microsoft XML standard. However, you are right that the JSON produced is similar to the XML (with no types) you provided: {"Table1":[{"Test":1.23345}]}

Comment: Please ignore the above comment. I was under the impression the conversion done by Newtonsoft used its own DataSet JSON format, not the standard serialization. I was relying on 100% lossless DataSet conversion, but I guess that is not possible.

Comment: Simply looking at the source, https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/DataTableConverter.cs, clearly reveals any non-integer gets converted to a double.