# Deserialization of JSON loses decimal when converting to datatable

Tags: c#, json, serialization, datatable, json.net

I have a JSON that looks like this

```
var json = "{\"Month\":1,\"Year\":\"2016\",\"Col1\":\"\",\"Forecast\":2121.00,\"etc\":\"etc\"}";
```

When I tried to deserialize it and convert to datatable, 2121.00 became 2121
losing its decimals and thus resulting to making the type of the column into int.

How can I deserialize it by retaining its value so it will still retain its decimal datatype in the datatable?

btw I'm using the Newtonsoft JSon using this method..

```
public string DataTableToJSONWithJSONNet(DataTable table)
    {
        string JSONString = string.Empty;
        JSONString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(table);
        return JSONString;
    }
```

Comment: Do you *have* to deserialize it to a datatable instead of using your own class? Also note that what you've shown isn't the JSON, but a C# string literal representation of the JSON (without leading and trailing quotes). The actual JSON wouldn't have backslashes escaping the property names - I suggest you remove those, leaving just the JSON itself.

Comment: Its the value that I came up after using this string method. I edit my post above.

Comment: It's not the actual value though. It may be what you're seeing in a debugger, but if you print the value to the screen, it won't have those backslashes...

Comment: It actually became an integer, when I tried to break point at the part where I'm binding my datatable into my gridview.

Comment: convert datatype to decimal if you are using double

Comment: No, the string didn't become an integer. I'm talking about the JSON representation in your question, not what happened after you parsed it.

Comment: I've changed it to be syntactically valid C# code. The other option would be to turn it into syntactically valid JSON, as Jon suggests.

Comment: Don't suppose you found an answer to this. I am having a similar issue when the API call deserializes my DataTable mine is Core 3.0 call and response from 4.7.2 API

Comment: Deserialize with [`JsonSerializerSettings.FloatParseHandling = FloatParseHandling.Decimal`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_FloatParseHandling.htm) as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17602364/3744182) by [oakio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/835720/oakio) to [Newtonsoft JSON- Conversion to/from DataSet causes Decimal to become Double?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17597594/3744182). ...

Comment: But note that integer JSON values will still get deserialized as `long` so if you have a mixture of integer and decimal column values your deserialized `DataTable` might come back with `long` column types rather than `decimal`.  See [.NET JSON DeserializeObject to datatable - Parsing problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60973783/3744182) for details.