# .NET JSON DeserializeObject to datatable - Parsing problem

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net, deserialization

When I try to deserialize a JSON string, the values of some JSON attributes are converted from float to int.

This is the JSON string:

```
{
  "skip": 0,
  "take": 5,
  "rows": [
    {
      "PRIJSLIJST": "I0109",
      "DIENST": "506",
      "PRIJS": 199.99,
      "BI_WAARDE": 199.99,
      "NI_WAARDE": 199.99
    }
  ]
}
```

The value "199.99" is deserialized to "199".

I also tried `JsonSerializerSettings`, but it didn't work either (I tried with different cultures).

```
Dim settings As New JsonSerializerSettings() With {.FloatParseHandling = FloatParseHandling.Decimal, .Culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")}
Dim dt As DataTable = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataTable)(strOutput_JSON, settings)
```

**UPDATE SOLUTION**

My initial values were assign to 0, so the datatype was set to an integer.
Then, I tried to replace my initial values with decimals, then the datatype was set to float/decimal.

Comment: Can you post the JSON?

Comment: Edited with JSON code

Comment: Is the problem solved then? If so, post the answer yourself.

Comment: See text below "UPDATE SOLUTION"

Answer (score 0):

Add the below imports -

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
```

Create a class for your DataTable deserialization like below -

```
Public Class DataTableRow
    Public PRIJSLIJST as String
    Public DIENST as String
    Public PRIJS as Decimal
    Public BI_WAARDE as Decimal
    Public NI_WAARDE as Decimal
End Class

Public Class DataTable
    Public skip as Integer
    Public take as Integer
    Public rows as List(Of String)()
End Class
```

And then Deserialize like below -

```
Dim DeSerialDataTable as DataTable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataTable)(strOutput_JSON)
```