# Force decimal type in class definition during serialization

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a class. One of the members of the class is having subtypes as Decimal. Default Json serializer (not directly used. Used by some no-sql libraries for read/write), converts these Decimal values as Double. Since, external library internally serializes the object, I'm looking for a way to add JsonProperty such that it forces `FloatParseHandling.Decimal` flag. I have found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17597594/newtonsoft-json-conversion-to-from-dataset-causes-decimal-to-become-double/17602364#17602364). But, there we are specifically setting the flag during serialization which I don't have access to.

```
class TestData
{
    [JsonProperty(???)] // I need to apply property only at this level.
    public List<Row> rows;
}

// this class is being used by other APIs.
class Row
{ 
    public string myString { get; set; }
    // this will have int, string, 'decimal' types. Decimal type gets auto converted to Double and gets rounded
    public List<dynamic> values { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: Then why not set it during De-serialisation, the part you do have access too (since it happens in your code, automatically or manually).

Comment: Just to clarify -- [`FloatParseHandling.Decimal`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_FloatParseHandling.htm) only applies when **reading** JSON text, not when writing.  So, to confirm, you want to ensure that `values` inside `Row` inside `TestData` are **deserialized** as `decimal`, correct?  Because that's what my answer does.

Comment: @dbc, writeJson is rounding up as well. For example, I have '123456789012345678.90123456' as dynamic type. But, writeJson rounds it by taking it as Double.

Comment: @KrunalModi - I just updated the [sample fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7vRkGH) to serialize the value `123456789012345678.90123456`, and it round-trips OK without data loss.  So we need to see a [mcve] to help you with this problem.  Are you sure you are correctly initializing your `dynamic` value as a `decimal` instead of a `double`?  You need to remember to put the `m` on the end like so for the compiler to interpret it as a decimal literal: `123456789012345678.90123456m`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`FloatParseHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_FloatParseHandling.htm) specifies *how floating point numbers, e.g. 1.0 and 9.9, are parsed when reading JSON text.*  (It is not applicable during writing or serialization, when Json.NET should write both `decimal` and `double` values with as much precision as necessary.)  There is no built-in attribute to temporarily toggle [`JsonReader.FloatParseHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader_FloatParseHandling.htm) during deserialization of a specific property.  When deserializing a statically typed property such as

```
List<decimal> values { get; set; }
```

this is not an issue because the serializer tells the reader the required floating-point type.  Only when deserializing to a `dynamic` property does this become problematic.

Thus what you can do is to create a [custom `JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) that temporarily resets the value of `JsonReader.FloatParseHandling`, then allocates and populates the object being deserialized, like so:

```
public class FloatParseHandlingConverter : JsonConverter
{
    readonly FloatParseHandling floatParseHandling;

    public FloatParseHandlingConverter(FloatParseHandling floatParseHandling)
    {
        this.floatParseHandling = floatParseHandling;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        var old = reader.FloatParseHandling;
        try
        {
            reader.FloatParseHandling = floatParseHandling;
            existingValue = existingValue ?? serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType).DefaultCreator();
            serializer.Populate(reader, existingValue);
            return existingValue;
        }
        finally
        {
            reader.FloatParseHandling = old;
        }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then apply it to your `rows` property as follows:

```
class TestData
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(FloatParseHandlingConverter), FloatParseHandling.Decimal)]
    public List<Row> rows;
}
```

Sample working [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7vRkGH).

As an aside, note that, if you have a dynamic property that might have a decimal value, like so:

```
public class Parent
{
    dynamic value { get; set; }
}
```

then applying the converter directly to the property will not work.  This is because, at the time [`JsonConverter.ReadJson()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_ReadJson.htm) is called, the reader has already advanced to the value string *and tokenized it as a `double`*.  Thus the converter must be applied to a container type or property, e.g.:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(FloatParseHandlingConverter), FloatParseHandling.Decimal)]
public class Parent
{
    // [JsonConverter(typeof(FloatParseHandlingConverter), FloatParseHandling.Decimal)] will not work
    dynamic value { get; set; }
}
```

This dovetails with the specific case of this question since you want the deserialized floating-point values inside `Row` to be interpreted as `decimal` only within `TestData`.