# How to write a JsonConverter to serialize and deserialize a custom struct containing a single value?

Tags: c#, serialization, struct, json.net, deserialization

I want to serialize and deserialize a custom struct. The serializing seems to work, but deserializing it back doesn't work

This is the struct :

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(PriceConverter))]
public struct Price
{
    private readonly decimal _value;

    public Price(Price value)
    {
        _value = value._value;
    }

    public Price(decimal value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator decimal(Price p)
    {
        return p._value;
    }

    public static implicit operator Price(decimal d)
    {
        return new Price(d);
    }
}
```

This is the JsonConverter :

```
class PriceConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(decimal?);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return serializer.Deserialize(reader) as Price?;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, (decimal)((Price)value));
    }
}
```

This is the class:

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Price Price { get; set; }
}
```

This is some test code:

```
Product product1 = new Product();
product1.Name = "Hans";
product1.Price = (decimal)2.3;

string priceSer = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product1);

Product product2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(priceSer);
```

product1 is correct.

```
?product1.Price

{MvcClient.Features.WFPBranch.Employee.Price}
    _value: 2.3
```

string priceSer contains : "{"Name":"Hans","Price":2.3}"

product2 however isn't correct. It should contain 2.3 but it contains 0. What is wrong ? ... How can I make it contain 2.3?

```
?product2.Price

{MvcClient.Features.WFPBranch.Employee.Price}
    _value: 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Your basic problem is that, in `ReadJson()`, `serializer.Deserialize(reader)` does not return what you think.  We can demonstrate that by debugging as follows:

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    var v = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    Console.WriteLine(v.GetType()); // prints System.Double
    return v as Price?;         
}
```

The value of `v` here turns out to be `double` not `decimal`.  And since your `Price` type does not have an implicit or explicit conversion from `double`, `v as Price?` returns a null nullable value.

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/t4e4O1).

Now, you might think you could resolve the problem by deserializing explicitly to `decimal` as follows:

```
class PriceConverter : JsonConverter<Price>
{
    public override Price ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Price existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) =>
        serializer.Deserialize<decimal>(reader);

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Price value, JsonSerializer serializer) =>
        serializer.Serialize(writer, (decimal)value);
}
```

And sure enough, `Price._value` will be deserialized.  But in doing so, a subtle bug is introduced, namely that, at the time that `ReadJson()` is called, `JsonTextReader` will already have recognized the incoming value as a `double` **and discarded the raw JSON token**.  Thus the additional precision of `decimal` will have been **lost**.

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/K6QRQP) which shows that a price value of `2.30m` is round-tripped as `2.3m`.

So what are your options to avoid this problem?

Firstly, you could serialize and deserialize globally with [`JsonSerializerSettings.FloatParseHandling = FloatParseHandling.Decimal`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_FloatParseHandling.htm), and also modify your converter to throw an exception in the event that the current value was already recognized to be `double`:

```
class PriceConverter : JsonConverter<Price>
{
    public override Price ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Price existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) =>
        reader.ValueType == typeof(double) ? throw new JsonSerializationException("Double value for Price") : serializer.Deserialize<decimal>(reader);

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Price value, JsonSerializer serializer) =>
        serializer.Serialize(writer, (decimal)value);
}

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    FloatParseHandling = FloatParseHandling.Decimal,
};
string priceSer = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product1, settings);
Product product2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(priceSer, settings);
```

Of course, this might have unexpected side-effects on how types containing `double` values are deserialized.

Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Me7wJO).

Secondly, you could apply `FloatParseHandlingConverter` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48180588/3744182) to *[Force decimal type in class definition during serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48179763/3744182)* to every class containing a `Price` and modify your converter to throw an exception as in the first option:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(FloatParseHandlingConverter), FloatParseHandling.Decimal)]
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Price Price { get; set; }
}
```

This avoids the need to make global changes to serialization settings but might be somewhat burdensome if your `Price` type is used widely.

Demo fiddle #4 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/h242ku).

Thirdly, *if you are flexible about your JSON format*, you could serialize `Price` as an object containing the price value, rather than a value:

```
class PriceConverter : JsonConverter<Price>
{
    class PriceDTO { public decimal Value { get; set; } }

    public override Price ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Price existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) =>
        serializer.Deserialize<PriceDTO>(reader).Value;

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Price value, JsonSerializer serializer) =>
        serializer.Serialize(writer, new PriceDTO { Value = value });
}
```

This avoids the need to make any changes to `FloatParseHandling` outside the scope of `Price`, but does result in more complex JSON

```json
{"Name":"Hans","Price":{"Value":2.30}}
```

Instead of

```json
{"Name":"Hans","Price":2.30}
```

Demo fiddle #5 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iCerno).

Notes:

- Your `PriceConverter.CanConvert(Type objectType)` returns `true` in the event that the incoming type is `typeof(decimal?)`, but it should instead check for `typeof(Price)`.

  `CanConvert()` is not called when the converter is applied directly via attributes, however, so this mistake is not symptomatic.
- Alternatively, if you inherit from [`JsonConverter<Price>`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm) rather than `JsonConverter`, you won't have to override `CanConvert()` at all, and your code will be simpler and cleaner.