# JSON.NET - How do I include Type Name Handling for primitive C# types that are stored in an array/list as Object type

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I am using Newtonsoft JSON.NET to serialize/deserialize stuff for me. But I have this list wherein they are of `Object` type:

```
var list = new List<Object>() 
{ 
    "hi there", 
    1,
    2.33  
};
```

When I serialize that with `TypeNameHandling` set to `TypeNameHandling.All`, I was expecting that it will also give a `$type` for each instance on the list but doesn't seem to be the case. Here is the actual output:

```
{
    "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Object, mscorlib]], mscorlib",
    "$values": [
        "hi there",
        1,
        2.33
    ]
}
```

I need this to have specific Type Name Handling for those primitive types because if I add an `Int32` value in to the list and when it comes back after deserializing it JSON.NET sets it as `Int64`. That is a big deal for me because I am trying to invoke some methods and to do that I need to compare the parameters and they MUST have the same types. Is there a way or a setting you can set in JSON.NET to achieve what I need?

I've seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914333/overriding-default-primitive-type-handling-in-json-net) but what it does is that he is trying to change the default behavior and always return `Int32` which is not what I'm looking for.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You'll need to wrap your primitives inside something like `TypeWrapper<T>` from [Deserialize specific enum into system.enum in Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31351262/deserialize-specific-enum-into-system-enum-in-json-net).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a wrapper class for primitive types, included implicit operators as you want:

```
class TypeWrapper
{
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator TypeWrapper(long value)
    {
        return new TypeWrapper { Value = value, Type = typeof(long).FullName };
    }

    public static implicit operator long(TypeWrapper value)
    {
        return (long)value.Value;
    }

    public static implicit operator TypeWrapper(int value)
    {
        return new TypeWrapper { Value = value, Type = typeof(int).FullName };
    }

    public static implicit operator int(TypeWrapper value)
    {
        return (int)value.Value;
    }
}
```

Then you will have element' types when serialize data:

```
var data = new List<TypeWrapper> { 1, 2L };
var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
Console.WriteLine(json);

// result: [{"Value":1,"Type":"System.Int32"},{"Value":2,"Type":"System.Int64"}]
```

Comment: I'm still hoping for a more direct way of doing it (i.e a simple setting change or something). But if there isn't any then this would probably what I will go for. Thanks

Comment: Working solution based on TypeWrapper: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Y0EQKP