# Deserialize object when property has IDictionary<string, string>

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

I saw this but it doesnot help me.

[Deserializing an object with a Dictionary<string, object> property (Newtonsoft.Json)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45868180/deserializing-an-object-with-a-dictionarystring-object-property-newtonsoft-j)

I am working on WCF Restful service. I have complicated JSON.
I have below data contracts

```
[DataContract]
public class TimestampPackageDC
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Timestamp { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Company { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ContactID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Area { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string PackageID { get; set; }
} // end of class TimestampPackageDC

[DataContract]
public class TimestampPackageExtraDC: TimestampPackageDC
{
    [DataMember]
    public IDictionary<string, string> ExtraInfo { get; set; }
} // end of class TimestampPackageExtraDC


 [DataContract]
public class GetAllUnprintedItemsResponse: BaseResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public TimestampPackageDC[] TimestampPackages { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public TimestampPackageExtraDC[] TimestampExtraInfoPackages { get; set; }

}
```

I am making REST service call like below

```
GetAllUnprintedItemsResponse upResponse = new GetAllUnprintedItemsResponse();
Request upRequest = new Request() { Name = "abc" };
string url = "http://localhost:2023/myservice/getdata";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(upRequest));
request.ContentLength = data.Length;
Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
requestStream.Close();

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Stream respStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(respStream);
string responseData = reader.ReadToEnd();

//getting error below
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.PopulateObject(responseData, upResponse);
```

I am getting JSON string like below

```
{
    "DocumentException": null,
    "Success": true,
    "TimestampExtraInfoPackages": [{
        "Area ": "AA",
        "Company": "XXX",
        "ContactID": "123",
        "PackageID": "P1",
        "Timestamp": "20090501163433360001",
        "ExtraInfo": [{
                "Key": "Key1",
                "Value": "value1"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Key2",
                "Value": "value2"
            }
        ]
    }],
    "TimestampPackages": []
}
```

Below is the error I am getting

**Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.String]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) 
like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path 'TimestampExtraInfoPackages[0].ExtraInfo', line 1, position 194.**

**SOLUTION:**

Thanks to Shiva, Brian and taffer. I used taffer advice and it worked. It looks we cannot use IDictionary.

I used below to solve my issue.

```
public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> ExtraInfo { get; set; }
```

I tried below but did not work got same error.

```
public IDictionary<string, string>[] ExtraInfo { get; set; }
```

Comment: Take that extra space out of `Area `. I think that is invalid JSON.

Comment: Dictionaries in JSON look like a normal JSON object, because JSON objects are dictionaries. What your JSON actually looks like here is a `List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>` for the `ExtraInfo` property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error message says the incoming `ExtraInfo` should be a JSON object but in your example it is a JSON array containing objects with `Key` and `Value` properties.

Either feed your service with the expected JSON string:

```
"ExtraInfo": {
            "Key1": "value1",
            "Key2": "value2"
        }
```

Or modify your contract to an array or list so it can accept a JSON array:

```
[DataMember]
public KeyValuePair<string, string>[] ExtraInfo { get; set; }
```

Comment: I am trying and will let you know

Comment: I am getting error.. working …   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string>[]'

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration of `ExtraInfo` should be an array.

```
public IDictionary<string, string>[] ExtraInfo { get; set; }
```

instead of

```
public IDictionary<string, string> ExtraInfo { get; set; }
```

EDIT

Here's the working code. I tried putting it on dotNetFiddle, but was/am getting some errors on dotnetfiddle.com [ including `System.Runtime.Serialization` ], hence pasting the working code below.

Note, your `ExtraInfo` will look like the following. But that's how your JSON also is. If you want to take the values from the `Key` and `Value` json keys respectively and construct a single dictionary or keyvaluepair entry, then you'd likely have to write a [custom Converter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm).

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace SoDeserializeJson_53936668
{
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract]
    public class TimestampPackageDC
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Timestamp { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Company { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string ContactID { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Area { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string PackageID { get; set; }
    } // end of class TimestampPackageDC

    [DataContract]
    public class TimestampPackageExtraDC : TimestampPackageDC
    {
        [DataMember]
        public IDictionary<string, string>[] ExtraInfo { get; set; }
    } // end of class TimestampPackageExtraDC


    [DataContract]
    public class GetAllUnprintedItemsResponse //: BaseResponse
    {
        [DataMember]
        public TimestampPackageDC[] TimestampPackages { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public TimestampPackageExtraDC[] TimestampExtraInfoPackages { get; set; }

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var json = @"
            {
                'DocumentException': null,
                'Success': true,
                'TimestampExtraInfoPackages': [{
                    'Area ': 'AA',
                    'Company': 'XXX',
                    'ContactID': '123',
                    'PackageID': 'P1',
                    'Timestamp': '20090501163433360001',
                    'ExtraInfo': [{
                            'Key': 'Key1',
                            'Value': 'value1'
                        },
                        {
                            'Key': 'Key2',
                            'Value': 'value2'
                        }
                    ]
                }],
                'TimestampPackages': []
            }".Replace("'","\"");

            GetAllUnprintedItemsResponse upResponse = new GetAllUnprintedItemsResponse();

            string responseData = json;

            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetAllUnprintedItemsResponse>(json);

            Console.WriteLine(data.TimestampExtraInfoPackages.First().ExtraInfo.Count());

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this result in an array of dictionaries that each have two entries, one for "Key" and one for "Value"?

Comment: I am trying and will let you know

Comment: @JonathonChase Correct. But that's how OP's sample JSON also is. OP hasn't explicitly stated that he was to deserialize the value in `Key` key and the value in `Value` key into a single entry containing the values in the `Key` key and `Value` key respectively, if you know what I mean. In that case he'd need to write a custom serializer.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because your JSON has an array of key-value pair objects, whereas a dictionary is serialized as a single object.

One solution is to change your `ExtraInfo` property to be a `KeyValuePair<string, string>[]` to match the JSON (or change the JSON to match your class) as suggested by @taffer.

However, there is another way.  You could keep your `ExtraInfo` property declared as it is and use a custom [`JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) to create and populate the dictionary during deserialization.

Here is the code you would need for the converter:

```
public class KvpArrayToDictionaryConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(IDictionary<string, string>).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var array = JArray.Load(reader);
        foreach (var obj in array.Children<JObject>())
        {
            dict.Add((string)obj["Key"], (string)obj["Value"]);
        }
        return dict;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To use the converter, just add a `[JsonConverter]` attribute to your `ExtraInfo` property like this:

```
    [DataMember]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(KvpArrayToDictionaryConverter))]
    public IDictionary<string, string> ExtraInfo { get; set; }
```

Working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1k7vNA

---

Another possible solution is to use a [`ContractResolver`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_IContractResolver.htm) to change the contract of the dictionary so that Json.Net sees it as an array of key-value pair objects.  See [Serialize dictionary as array (of key value pairs)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12751354/10263) for more info on this approach.  However if you go that route you will need to change the declaration of your `ExtraInfo` property from an `IDictionary` interface to a concrete `Dictionary`, otherwise Json.Net will give you an error about not being able to create an instance of an interface.