# Dictionary<string, object> returns long instead of int

Tags: c#

I have a dictionary that looks like this that gets Deserialized from a json file to a C# Dictionary

```
  {
      "Name": "option1",
      "Settings": {
        "setting1": 20,
        "setting2": 2
      }
  }
```

So I Deserialize this to an object which works but when i try to get that value out of the dictionary it becomes a long instead of an int

```
        if (!settings.TryGetValue("setting1", out object setting))
        {
            setting = 10;
        }
```

Then somewhere else I do something like this:

```
if ((int)setting > 10) {//do something}
```

Then it gives me the error that an int64 cant be converted to an int32

Deserialization process:

```
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Startup.SettingsPath))
                {
                    SettingsModel settings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SettingsModel>(reader.ReadToEnd()).Applications;

                    return settings

                }
```

SettingsModel:

```
public class SettingsModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IDictionary<string, object> Settings { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I strongly suspect that it's the deserialization process that's giving you an unexpected value here. Please provide a [mcve] showing how you're converting the JSON to a `Dictionary`.

Comment: JSON has no `int` or `long`, just numbers, as opposed to C#'s zoo of types. If you don't specify the types to use when deserializing, the deserialization logic has to guess which type to use. You wanted `int`, it gave you `long`. Either accept that, or consult the documentation on how to make it do something else. (The fact that you have to use `object` here is a sign that there's a probably a better, more specific way to deserialize things.)

Comment: Ok thanks ill just accept that its a long

Comment: Ohh okay. what you mean with **actual** json? I provided the json in the first part of the question

Comment: I believe that in the specific case of JSON.NET, if the number involved is not floating-point (i.e. has no period in the representation) and will not exceed the range of a `long`, it will use `long`, otherwise it will use `BigInteger`. Don't quote me on that, though. And I don't know if it's in the JSON.NET documentation itself; I couldn't immediately find it. Of course, if one of the `settingX` turns out to be `"banana"`, casting to a `long` will fail. If possible, use a typed model where the settings have fixed names and types, rather than a generic `Dictionary<string, object>`.

Comment: See dotnetfiddle.net/Y0EQKP from comment in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35592256/json-net-how-do-i-include-type-name-handling-for-primitive-c-sharp-types-that

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to deserialize the number as an integer, you could implement a custom `JsonConverter` as:

```
public class CustomConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(object).Equals(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken jToken = JValue.ReadFrom(reader);
        switch (reader.TokenType)
        {
            case JsonToken.Integer:
                return jToken.Value<int>();
            case JsonToken.String:
                return jToken.Value<string>();
            // ...and so on...
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException($"Unknown JsonToken: '{reader.TokenType}'.");
        }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Pass an instance of the custom converter class to the `DeserializeObject()` method as:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SettingsModel>(reader.ReadToEnd(), new CustomConverter());
```

Comment: I have little experience with JSON.NET, but wouldn't it be more effective to check first if `reader.TokenType` is `JsonToken.Integer`? It makes little sense to pre-emptively try to parse *everything* as an integer -- `TryParse` is relatively expensive. (This code also ignores integer arrays, I think, but that wouldn't be a problem for the JSON as posted since it doesn't have any.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert You are absolutely right. I have improved my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I had an instance that required a one off for this situation. I implemented the following.

```
private int GetInt(KeyValuePair<string, object> pair)
{
    object value = pair.Value;
    Type valueType = value.GetType();
    if (property.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(int)))
    {
       value = Convert.ToInt32(value);
    }
}
```