# JSON Deserialization - int is automatically converted to long

Tags: c#, json, json.net

If I deserialize some JSON to a dictionary of objects like so:

```
var properties = "{\"property1\":\"\",\"property2\":2}";

var dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(properties);

Console.WriteLine(dictionary["property2"].GetType()); // Prints System.Int64
```

The integer-valued property `property2` is getting automatically deserialized as a `long` and not an `int`.

Can I convert automatically to `int`?

Comment: This is, apparently, the intended functionality.  When you deserialize to `object`, Json.NET will chose an appropriate concrete data type; for integer values it chooses `long` unconditionally.  If you don't like that, see e.g. [How do I change the default Type for Numeric deserialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8297541/3744182) or [Overriding Default Primitive Type Handling in Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9914333/3744182).  In fact this may be a duplicate of those two, agree?

Comment: `var properties = "{\"property1\":\"\",\"property2\":2}"; var t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, int?>>(properties); Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", t.ToList().Select(kvp => kvp.Value?.GetType())));` run that...